# SQL Transpose Multiple Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, transpose, unpivot

[image: Original Data]

[image: Required Result]

I have the Data in Fig1 and need to transpose the Columns to Rows as in Fig2 ( Required Result).

This will be for multiple years and periods

Comment: Do a UNION ALL, one select for each Description type.

Comment: what sql platform are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Division, Period, 'Total Cost' as Description, TotalCost as Value
from MyTable
union
select Division, Period, 'Discount' as Description, Discount as Value
from MyTable
union
select Division, Period, 'Net Sales' as Description, NetSales as Value
from MyTable
union
select Division, Period, 'Net Returns' as Description, NetReturns as Value
from MyTable
union
select Division, Period, 'Gross Sales' as Description, GrossSales as Value
from MyTable
union
select Division, Period, 'Gross Returns' as Description, GrossReturns as Value
from MyTable
```

You can also wrap this in a view, then do a select on the view with whatever ordering or filtering that you need

Comment: Thank you Joe, just couldn't work it out, tried most complicated code ever.

Comment: @LDD - great, I'm glad you are done.  If this question is completed, please close this question by accepting an answer.  (btw... I answered first)

Answer (score 2):

On any platform UNION ALL will work.  Some platforms have UNPIVOT, but you didn't say what you are using.

```
SELECT Division, Period, 'Total Cost' AS DESCRIPTION, TotalCost as Value
FROM A_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY

UNION ALL

SELECT Division, Period, 'Discount' AS DESCRIPTION, DISCOUNT AS Value
FROM A_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY

UNION ALL

SELECT Division, Period, 'Net Sales' AS Descripion, NETSALES AS Value
FROM A_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY

UNION ALL

SELECT Division, Period, 'Net Returns' AS DESCRIPTION, NETRETURNS AS Value
FROM A_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY

UNION ALL

SELECT Division, Period, 'Gross Sales' AS DESCRIPTION, GROSSSALES AS Value
FROM A_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY

UNION ALL

SELECT Division, Period, 'Gross Returns' AS DESCRIPTION, GROSSRETURNS AS Value
FROM A_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am impressed with the creative table name.

Comment: @LDD - [I_SAY].[DONT_MOCK_THE_TABLE_NAME]